# Arc graph layout in GraphViz

Tags: graphviz, dot

How could I draw an [arc graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_diagram) in GraphViz? I can't force nodes to stand in one line.

[image: arc graph]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, I post some suggestion here. The following code solve the problem of force nodes to stand in one line.

```
digraph "test-graph" {
    graph [rankdir=LR]
    node[shape=circle, color=lightblue,label="",style=filled,width=0.3];
    edge[arrowhead=none,splines=line];
    1->2;
    2->3;
    edge[splines=curved];
    1->3[constraint=false];
}
```

but don't have power for semi-circle edge. You can try other tools,such as Tikz.